# SAS: Looping over column names

Tags: sas

I have a data set with the following structure:

```
data account;
   input Index c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 ;
   datalines;
4 30 20 10 30 40 20 
3 50 20 30 50 10 20
;
run;
```

In my file, there are 150+ columns of the "c"-Type containing numbers. In each line, I would like to sum up the c: columns up to the Index variable and put the sum into a new column. In the first line the Index variable is 4, so the result should be sum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4. In the second line, the Index is 3, so it should be sum = c1 + c2 + c3.

How can I address the columns like this? Do I have to read them into an array first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
data want;
  set account;
  array vars c:;
  sum=0;
  do i=1 to index;
     sum+vars(i);
  end;
  drop i;
  run;
```

Comment: thanks, but this way "sum" becomes a total sum over all lines as well. How can i tell the loop to reset the sum-variable for each line?

Comment: Put sum=0 before the do loop.

Comment: ok, it works - although i'm not entirely sure why. Is the whole datastep repeated for each line?

Comment: @user2394066 Are you asking whether the code in the data step is repeated once for each row in the dataset?  If so, yes.

Comment: Shenglin, I would not use `sum+vars[i];`, because that unnecessarily retains `sum` which causes the above problem.  Just write it out (`sum=sum+vars[i];`) or if vars[i] can be missing, `sum=sum(sum,vars[i]);`.